# Build VueJS 3 application as a single ES Module bundle?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, es6-modules

I have a Vue3 project which I configured with typescript and a `main.ts` entry file with one single default export.

```js
import { App, createApp } from "vue";
import { createIntl } from "vue-intl";

import Application from "./App.vue";
import { AppProps, Settings } from "types";

let appRef = {} as App<Element>;

const AppLifecycle = {
  mount: (container: HTMLElement, appProps: AppProps, settings: Settings) => {
    const { themeUrl, userPreferences } = settings;
    const { language } = userPreferences;

    appRef = createApp(Application, { ...appProps, themeUrl });
    appRef.use(
      createIntl({
        locale: language,
        defaultLocale: "en",
        messages: messages[language],
      })
    );
    appRef.mount(container);
  },
  unmount: (_: HTMLElement) => {
    appRef.unmount();
  },
};

export default AppLifecycle;
```

I'd like to build this as a single ES Module bundle in order to integrate it inside a private platform which has this requirements:

> the app’s bundle must be a JavaScript ES Module;

> the default export of the app must be an object to handle the app’s lifecycle (the `AppLifecycle` object above)

From a boilerplate project (written in React + Typescript) they're using the following webpack configuration:

```json
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: "css-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

From what I've understood Vue3 comes using webpack4 under the hood and the configuration can be tuned, till a certain degree, using a webpack chain inside `vue.config.js`. Moreover, the `vue-cli` can be used to specify a target (for instance `--target lib`) but I don't think ES modules are supported this way. I've made an attempt using the following configuration but I don't know if this is the right way.

```json
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization.set("splitChunks", false);
    config.plugins.delete("prefetch");
    config.plugins.delete("preload");
  },
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
  filenameHashing: false,
};
```

I didn't find any detailed resources on how to build specifically a single ES Module with a single typescript entry file using Vue3 so I'm asking here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to switch to Vite for this purpose

Comment: @EstusFlask which is the big advantage on using Vite over Vue? I'm asking since I don't know the framework and some insights on my specific context would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're comparing oranges to apples. Vue is a framework. Vue CLI and Vite are tools. Vue CLI is based on Webpack. Vite is based on Rollup. Vite provides ESM output out of the box. Vue CLI doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by upgrading `vue-cli` to version 5 which among the various changes takes into account Webpack 5 that handles the ES module generation https://next.cli.vuejs.org/migrations/migrate-from-v4.html#webpack-5

I've changed the `vue.config.js` file to be compliant with the boilerplate one I've posted. Like the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: "./src/main.ts",
    experiments: {
      outputModule: true,
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false,
    },
    output: {
      library: {
        type: "module",
      },
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.delete("prefetch");
    config.plugins.delete("preload");
  },
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
  filenameHashing: false,
};
```

I prefer this solution instead of using Vite as [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask) suggested since I don't know the tool and I prefer sticking to Webpack being the same used by the target platform.